# Why does readBin() return different values even with the same parameters?

Tags: r, binaryfiles, mnist

I'm reading MNIST image files into R using a function that relies on`readBin()`. However, running the function line-by-line I see that `readBin()` returns different values for the same line of code (without any change of parameters). How come?

```
#Getting the data
> download.file("http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz",
+               "t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz")

#unzipped the .gz file manually out of R. The extracted file is 'train-images.idx3-ubyte'

#Using file() to read the 'train-images.idx3-ubyte' file
> f = file("train-images.idx3-ubyte", 'rb')

#this is what 'f' is:
> f
A connection with                                     
description "train-images.idx3-ubyte"
class       "file"                   
mode        "rb"                     
text        "binary"                 
opened      "opened"                 
can read    "yes"                    
can write   "no" 

#The following lines show the execution of readBin with the same parameters, though giving a different value each time

> readBin(f, 'integer', n = 1, size = 4, endian = 'big')
[1] 2051
> readBin(f, 'integer', n = 1, size = 4, endian = 'big')
[1] 60000
> readBin(f, 'integer', n = 1, size = 4, endian = 'big')
[1] 28
> readBin(f, 'integer', n = 1, size = 4, endian = 'big')
[1] 28
> readBin(f, 'integer', n = 1, size = 4, endian = 'big')
[1] 0
```

Comment: It goes on in reading the file. The first call reads the first bytes; then the second call reads from the position left after the first call and so on.

Comment: Thanks @nicola! But then why aren't the chunks of bytes read in each call equal? What causes the inconsistency?

Comment: Apparently I didn't make myself clear. `readBin` reads from the position left from the last call. In each call you say to read 4 bytes. So the first call reads the first 4 bytes from the file. The second call reads bytes 5-8. The third bytes 9-12 and so on. It's like reading a sentence word by word. Say you have the sentence "Hello everybody! How are you?". That sentence is like your file. Your call to `readBin` is like: "read a word at the time". The first call will return "Hello", the second "everybody" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You open `file` connection and never close it. So the result is what you experienced. You just read next number.

Repeating the sequence

- open connection
- readBin
- close connection

Will give you consistent results.

Or using `readBin("the_file__not_the_connection", 'integer', n = 1, size = 4, endian = 'big')` as well.